# qml file can't call function to pyd file

Tags: python, qt, qml, cython, pyside2

There is qml file can't call function to pyd file problem.

There are several files:

i.   main.py       -> python.exe run entry

ii.  mainWidget.py -> show MyItem.qml ui and setContextProperty to MyItem.qml

iii. MyItem.qml    -> when you click mouse area will call MyObect function "cppMethod" and "cppSlot" in mainWidget.py

iv.  setup.py      -> build extension file to generate pyd used

v.   mainWidget.pyd -> generate by Cython

In mainWidget.py, there is MyObject class, in this class, function "cppMethod" and "cppSlot" will print log on python.exe

And then I call "setContextProperty" function to register "myobject" to MyItem.qml so that MyItem.qml will recognize "myobject" object.

When I run main.py on python.exe, it will show a widget.
Try to click in this widget, it will call MyObect function "cppMethod" and "cppSlot". It worked!!!

It will show:

```
qml: start
call the c++ method with Hello from QMLTest
call the c++ slot with 12345
qml: end
```

After that, I try to protect the code, so I use Cython(with setup.py) to generate file "mainWidget.pyd".

So I replace mainWidget.pyd for mainWidget.py.

When I run main.py with python.exe with "mainWidget.pyd", I click mouse area in the widget, it will show

```
"TypeError: Property 'cppMethod' of object MyObject(0x21822d07430) is not a function".
```

It means MyItem.qml doesn't recognize "myobject".

Is there any way to fix this problem?? How to fix this problem??

ps. I use Python version 3.6.2, Qt version 5.6.2

main.py

```
import mainWidget
widget = mainWidget.main()
```

mainWidget.py

```
import os
import sys
import PySide2
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtQuickWidgets import *

class MyObject(PySide2.QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyObject, self).__init__(parent)

    @PySide2.QtCore.Slot(str)
    def cppMethod(self, msg):
        print ("call the c++ method with ",msg)

    @PySide2.QtCore.Slot(int)
    def cppSlot(self, number):
        print ("call the c++ slot with", number)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickWidget()
    myclass = MyObject()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("myObject",myclass)
    relativeUrl = QUrl(".//MyItem.qml")
    view.setSource(relativeUrl)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

MyItem.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQml 2.2

Item {
    width: 100; height: 100
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("start")
            myObject.cppMethod("Hello from QML")
            myObject.cppSlot(12345)
            console.log("end")
        }
    }
}
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("mainWidget.py")
)
```

Comment: Not cython expert: What I think is that cython does not implement the MOC so QML does not recognize that methods.

Comment: On the other hand I do not see the need to use cython for the code they show, the idea of cython is to optimize certain parts of the application and in the case of the connection between QML and the slots is not necessary because it is invoked using C++, I would recommend creating functions that are optimized and invoking them in the slots.

Comment: I embed Python in application, so i try to use python function to call some c++ function. It just a function name.

Comment: as I say, create a different file where the heavy operations are then use cython to optimize and then call them in the slot, that is, do not use cython in the slot but only in heavy tasks.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks a lot. I' very confused that why qml can't call function to pyd file. Maybe you are right!! Cython doesn't implement moc function... Now I need to use .py file to get function call from QML first, then call .pyd function again. But I think that it may have some solution to solve it...

Comment: You might try the [Cython option `binding=True`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives). I think the problem has been misdiagnosed and that PyQt just makes an overly restrictive type check for a Python function. It's just possible that the binding option will let a Cython function pass that type check.

Comment: @DavidW  I try to add binding flag equal true, like setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("mainWidget.py", compiler_directives={'binding': True})
)      But it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Cython does not implement the MOC, so QML can not invoke the methods (if the generated .c is reviewed, it is observed that everything is implemented except the @Slot that the MOC creates).

A workaround is to separate the code that uses the slot and use cython in that part after you import and use the compiled code in the slot.